# How to use SKU:Basic with google places api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Google states, that SKU:Basic with google places is free:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#new-pricing-for-the-places-api

I'm using google maps javascript API and use autocomplete (with react).

How can I activate SKU:Basic?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't activate `SKU:Basic Data` anywhere it will be taken into account automatically according to the list of fields that you specify in your details request. The basic group of fields according to the documentation is the following

> The Basic category includes the following fields:
>   address_component, adr_address, alt_id, formatted_address, geometry, icon, id, name, permanently_closed, photo, place_id, plus_code, scope, type, url, utc_offset, vicinity

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Also you should understand that `SKU:Basic Data` refers only to the data part of details request. But you will always trigger `SKU: Places Details`. In other words when you try to get a details for a place `getPlaceDetails()` will trigger the following SKUs:

- SKU: Places Details (17$ per 1000, always)
- SKU: Basic Data (Free, if you request basic fields)
- SKU: Contact Data (3$ per 1000, if you request contact fields)
- SKU: Atmosphere Data (5$ per 1000, if you request atmosphere fields)

If you don't specify fields in request all SKUs are included which results in 25$. In case of autocomplete followed by place details request you will get

- SKU: Autocomplete (included with Places Details) – Per Session (Free)
- Details SKUs as described before

That means that price for place autocomplete widget varies from 17$ per 1000 requests to 25$ per 1000 requests depending on the list of fields that you specify in details requests.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

If you have any price specific questions I would suggest reaching directly to Google support team via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Comment: It's taken me like 3 days of on-and-off research and close reading for me to reach this same conclusion. Glad I found your answer to back it up!

Comment: Same here, lots of time spent reading Google's docs, glad I found this answer. Google's documentation on this topic is huge and confusing. I feel like they purposely made the pricing model as confusing as possible.

Comment: @xomena So If I request only geometry from SKU:Basic Data there will be no charges. Correct ?

Comment: @RakeshBhatt No, you will pay for request always. You won't pay the data, but request itself is always charged.

Comment: @xomena This is madness. My app currently do 500k request per month using place sdk which will be deprecated soon. How can I replace it with place API :|

Comment: What is with amazon/google/etc making billing so complicated you need a certification just to pay them? Seems like bad business.

Comment: only place on the entire internet with a straight answer on this, you should manage google's API department my friend

Comment: This Google places autocomplete is so confusing and expensive like crazy,